# what do 'return vacation' and 'return student' mean?

Tags: python, return

Python 3.9 // Pycharm community ver.

```
def person(age):
    print("I am a person")
    def student(major):
        print("I like learning")
        def vacation(place):
            print("But I need to take breaks")
            print(age,"|",major,"|",place)
        return vacation
    return student

person(12)("Math")("beach")

------------------------------------------------------------
I am a person
I like learning
But I need to take breaks
12 | Math | beach
```

Hello guys.
I can't understand meaning of return 'vacation'(and 'student')
Why should I type return vacation and return student?
I changed return 1 or a.. but it doesn't work.

Help me please^^~

Comment: This is a function returning a function returning a function. Think of it step by step and it should be clear

Comment: It's doing the *same thing return always does*.

Comment: vacation is a only name of function, then what's the value of vacation or student?

Comment: `person(12)` forms a closure which returns a function which accepts a single argument ("Math"), this function forms a closure which returns a function which accepts a single argument ("beach"). Each of these functions inherits the enclosing scope. Read up on [closures](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/closure), they aren't specific to Python and are very common in functional programming paradigms.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two points to take into account. First, you can take multiple arguments in one function: `def person(age, major, place)`. Second, there is no need to `return` anything since the function is not processing anything to return, but only printing output. This makes it possible to clean up your code significantly:

```
def person(age, major, place):
    print("I am a person")
    print("I like learning")
    print("But I need to take breaks")
    print(str(age),"|",major,"|",place)
    
person(12, 'Math', 'beach')
```